# grails not using cache

Tags: hibernate, grails, ehcache

I've noticed a slow down on my site and after turning on `debug 'org.hibernate.SQL'` I see where the troubles are.  I've set a domain class to be cached using....

```
class Foo{
    ...
    static mapping ={
       cache 'read-only'
    }

    String name         //<-- simple data type, no associations
    String description  //<-- simple data type, no associations

}
```

My hibernate config looks like this...

```
hibernate {
    cache.use_second_level_cache=true
    cache.use_query_cache=true
    cache.provider_class='net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheProvider'
}
```

my query looks like this (in a web flow)...

```
def wizardFlow = {
    ...
    def flow.foos = Foo.list([sort:"name", order:"asc", cache:true]) 
    // def flow.foos = Foo.findAll([cache:true]) <--- same result, no caching

}
```

I would think that either the query cache or second level cache would stop the database from being hit but my log is loaded with...

```
select ... from thing thing0_ where thing0_.id=?
select ... from thing thing0_ where thing0_.id=?
select ... from thing thing0_ where thing0_.id=?
select ... from thing thing0_ where thing0_.id=?
```

Can anyone shed some light on what might be happening?  Other queries are acting as they should!

I'm using Grails 1.3.7

Lastly, here is my ehcache.xml...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="ehcache.xsd" >
    <diskStore path="java.io.tmpdir"/>
    <cacheManagerEventListenerFactory class="" properties=""/>
    <defaultCache
       maxElementsInMemory="1000000"
       eternal="false"
       timeToIdleSeconds="3600"
       timeToLiveSeconds="7200"
       overflowToDisk="true"
       diskPersistent="false"
       />

    <cache name="org.hibernate.cache.UpdateTimestampsCache"
      maxElementsInMemory="10000"
      timeToIdleSeconds="300"
       />
    <cache name="org.hibernate.cache.StandardQueryCache"
      maxElementsInMemory="10000"
      timeToIdleSeconds="300"
       />

</ehcache>
```

Comment: Have you checked for an N+1 select problem?

Comment: My real life entity has only one association (1 to 1) and it too is cached the same way

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a problem we had as well which was basically the N+1 select problem. This is what we did:

```
import org.hibernate.FetchMode as FM
```

...

```
def crit= item.createCriteria();
def itemList = crit.listDistinct
    {

      fetchMode "subItem", FM.JOIN
      cache true
      order("name","asc")
    }
```

You should be able to switch out subItem to what ever you have associated and that should help.

Comment: no effect.  It did cache one of my calls but all others hit the db

Comment: Also did you you add cache true to the criteria? I updated the answer to see if that helped

Comment: yes, still no change. I updated my question to show the child class (bar).  I think this is causing the problem.  I might be forced to deal with the assoc. differently.

Comment: Do you have the 'static belongsTo = Foo' in the bar domain object?

Comment: edited my question and made changes to my domain.  Still no cache :(

Comment: Michael if you want email me directly and we can try and work this out if you are up for it.